PWM modulation on keil for board kl25z
I am trying to create a PWM that does the following: At first the arm of the servo motor must be in neutral position. Then, every 0.5 seconds the position of the arm of the servo will move by 30 degrees. Code is written in C and for the board freedom kl25z.
Here is the code that I tried. The arm of the servo does not responds at all.
#include <MKL25Z4.H>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "utils.h"

int main (void) {
    SIM->SCGC5 |= 0x1000; /* enable clock to Port D */
    PORTD->PCR[2] = 0x0400; /* PTD1 used by TPM0 PIN DEL PRIMER SERVOMOTOR */
    SIM->SCGC6 |= 0x01000000; /* enable clock to TPM0 */
    SIM->SOPT2 |= 0x01000000; /* use MCGFLLCLK as timer counter clock */
    while (1) {
        TPM0->SC = 0; /* disable timer */
        TPM0->CONTROLS[3].CnSC = 0x20 | 0x08; /* edge-aligned, pulse high */
        TPM0->MOD = 299999; /* Set up modulo register for 50 Hz */
        TPM0->CONTROLS[3].CnV = 15000; /* Set up channel value for 5% dutycycle for 0 degree */
        TPM0->SC = 0x0C; /* enable TPM0 with prescaler /16 */
        Delay(5000000);
        TPM0->CONTROLS[3].CnV = 17499; /* Set up channel value for  for duty cycle 5.833 30 degree */
        Delay(5000000);
        TPM0->CONTROLS[3].CnV = 19999; /* Set up channel value for  duty cycle 6.66333 value 19999 60 degree servo*/
        TPM0->SC = 0x0C;
        Delay(5000000);
        TPM0->CONTROLS[3].CnV = 22500;
        TPM0->SC = 0x0C;
        Delay(5000000);
    }
}


For real-time performance, you should use hardware timers instead of busy-wait delays. Also you really should make an effort in replacing all "magic numbers" with named constants.
